# Why my custom module configuration are not getting created on module install?

Tags: configuration

I have created one custom module with config/install folder. This install folder contain content type yml. Basically on install of custom module new content type should be created.
When I use drush en my_custom_module, all configuration are getting imported successfully. But when I do drush cim only module is installed but configuration(mycustommodule/config/install) are missing. Do we need to do any changes so that while doing global cim import it should import my config/install level configuration too.

Comment: Then the module was not correctly installed on the site where you run drush cex.

Comment: I recheck multiple time but module is installed without any error but config/install is ignored. While doing cim I didn't found any error.

Comment: Did you export the configuration after installing the module?

Comment: ok..Yes I export the configuration when my module was enable using drush cex. Then I placed all require yml file from config/sync folder to my custom module config folder ie config/install. So in short in core.extensions.yml file I have entry to enable my custom module. I tested with fresh database where my module is not install and tired drush cim. Without any error my module is getting install but config/install folder is ignored.

Comment: *I placed all require yml file from config/sync folder to my custom module config folder ie config/install* ... you don't need to do that when deploying through drush cex/cim.

Comment: ok, means configuration present inside config/sync would only be imported. Actually my aim was to use this module in different site. So I was targeting that on doing drush cim, module should be install with its configuration. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You know that drush cim/cex is only for cloned sites, not for different sites?

Comment: Yes you are correct and I m absolutely aware of this.